# Ruby on Rails | one form - three tables (can't save the form content)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-attributes

I am trying to write an app - simple form for user's details which saves data to three different tables (1.users, 2.companies, 3.adresses). 
I have set some assosiations using belongs_to and has_many, and also use nested_attributes and fields_for to build one form. But I can't save data.
I am a newbie, so probably I'm making some stupid mistakes, but I cannot really find them since 3 days. Also tried to look in google and here, among forum posts, but didn't find a code, where the problem was connected with child class. My assosiations between user, company and adress are quite weird. Can anyone help me?

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>

    <h5>Personal Details</h5>
      <%= f.input :firstname, label: 'Your First Name:' %>
      <%= f.input :lastname, label: 'Your Last Name:' %>
      <%= f.input :email, label: 'Your Email:' %>
      <%= f.input :dateofbirth, label: 'Your Date of Birth:' %>
      <%= f.input :phonenumber, label: 'Your Phone Number' %>
    <h5>Adress</h5>

      <%= f.fields_for :adresses do |g| %>
          <%= g.input :street, label: 'Street:' %>
          <%= g.input :city, label: 'City:' %>
          <%= g.input :zipcode, label: 'Zip Code:' %>
          <%= g.input :country, label: 'Country:' %>
      <% end %>

     <h5>Company</h5>  
     <%= f.fields_for :companies do |h| %>
          <%= h.input :name, label: 'Name:' %>
     <% end %>      

     <%= f.fields_for :adresses do |i| %>
          <%= i.input :comstreet, label: 'Street:' %>  
          <%= i.input :comcity, label: 'City:' %>  
          <%= i.input :comzipcode, label: 'Zip Code:' %>  
          <%= i.input :comcountry, label: 'Country:' %>  
      <% end %>

      <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :users
  belongs_to :adress,  inverse_of: :users

  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname, :email
  validates_length_of :firstname, :maximum => 100
  validates_length_of :lastname, :maximum => 100
end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :companies
  belongs_to :adress, inverse_of: :companies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

adress.rb

```
class Adress < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :adresses
  has_many :companies, inverse_of: :adresses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :companies
end
```

users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
   @user = User.new 
   @company = Company.new
   @adress = Adress.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save 
        redirect_to root_path
    end    
  end    

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :dateofbirth, 
    :phonenumber, company_attributes: [:name], 
    adress_attributes: [:street,:city, :zipcode, :country, :comstreet, 
    :comctiy, :comzipcode, :comcountry] )
  end    
end
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?
Also check the spelling in your user_params ... :comcity is incorrect.

Comment: I can't even save, so i can't read an error list. But here is a screen what happens in my console after I click on submit: https://gyazo.com/d7515286a8241d95b09553e29406e582

Answer (score 0):

In your **user.rb** file:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :users
  belongs_to :adress,  inverse_of: :users

  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname, :email
  validates_length_of :firstname, :maximum => 100
  validates_length_of :lastname, :maximum => 100
  # add nested attributes here not in other models
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :companies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses

end
```

Also, in your controller: carefully check the names of parameters passed. `address_attributes` misspelled

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :dateofbirth, 
    :phonenumber, company_attributes: [:name], 
    address_attributes: [:street,:city, :zipcode, :country, :comstreet, 
    :comctiy, :comzipcode, :comcountry] )
  end
```

In the view, remove multiple form elements for address. You wrote twice.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in the code and able to save the form, please check

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>

    <h5>Personal Details</h5>
      <%= f.input :firstname, label: 'Your First Name:' %>
      <%= f.input :lastname, label: 'Your Last Name:' %>
      <%= f.input :email, label: 'Your Email:' %>
      <%= f.input :dateofbirth, label: 'Your Date of Birth:' %>
      <%= f.input :phonenumber, label: 'Your Phone Number' %>
    <h5>Adress</h5>

      <%= f.fields_for :adress_attributes do |g| %>
          <%= g.input :street, label: 'Street:' %>
          <%= g.input :city, label: 'City:' %>
          <%= g.input :zipcode, label: 'Zip Code:' %>
          <%= g.input :country, label: 'Country:' %>
      <% end %>

     <h5>Company</h5>  
     <%= f.fields_for :company_attributes do |h| %>
          <%= h.input :name, label: 'Name:' %>
            <%= h.fields_for :adress_attributes do |i| %>
              <%= i.input :street, label: 'Street:' %>  
              <%= i.input :city, label: 'City:' %>  
              <%= i.input :zipcode, label: 'Zip Code:' %>  
              <%= i.input :country, label: 'Country:' %>  
           <% end %>
     <% end %>      



      <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :users
  belongs_to :adress,  inverse_of: :users

  validates_presence_of :firstname, :lastname, :email
  validates_length_of :firstname, :maximum => 100
  validates_length_of :lastname, :maximum => 100
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :companies
  belongs_to :adress, inverse_of: :companies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :adress
end
```

adress.rb

```
class Adress < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, inverse_of: :adresses
  has_many :companies, inverse_of: :adresses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :companies
end
```

users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def new
   @user = User.new 
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save 
        redirect_to root_path
    end    
  end    

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :dateofbirth, 
    :phonenumber, company_attributes: [:name, adress_attributes: [:street, 
    :ctiy, :zipcode, :country]], 
    adress_attributes: [:street,:city, :zipcode, :country] )
  end    
end
```

It is working now and able to save user, address and company with company address.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your advices! Actually, I still can't save it :( here is the error from the console: https://gyazo.com/2db0320c2a5b9a9bd1e3785672a157c5

Comment: @pigeonfield you are missing address_attributes of company and try to check errors with save! it will raise exception so you will be able to find exact error.

Comment: you have to use h.adress_attributes in company_attributes section.